# Change & Save Button Text onLongClick using sharedpreferences

Tags: android, button, sharedpreferences, android-alertdialog, onlongclicklistener

I want to change & save button text onLongClick permanently(until & unless I change it again). [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n56sp.png) is screenshot of overall code. But when I close the App & reopen it, the Button text remains default. What mistake am I doing?

```
package com.demo.buttontextedit;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private Button btn;
    private EditText edit;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
        btn.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                showDialog(edit.getText().toString());
                return true;
            }
        });
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked Button" +
                        btn.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void showDialog(String str) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("input text");
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.dialog_view, null);
        final EditText edit_dialog = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_dialog);
        edit_dialog.setText(str);
        builder.setView(view);

        builder.setNegativeButton("cancel", null);
        builder.setPositiveButton("confirm", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("myPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putString("Name", edit_dialog.getText().toString());
                editor.commit();
                btn.setText(sharedPreferences.getString("Name", ""));
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to update your button text from `onCreate()` according to the value in sharedpreference.

Answer (score 3):

you are missing get text from shared preferences on Oncrete activity.
Solution

put this lines :
if (sharedPreferences.getString("Name", "").equals(""))
{

```
btn.setText("YES");
```

}else{

```
btn.setText(sharedPreferences.getString("Name", "YES"));
```

}

below this line :
btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

Answer (score 1):

Flow of control causing this behavior.

you need to fetch data from preference in **`oncreate`** and set it on the `button` 
like

```
oncreate(Bundle b) {
// initialize preference and layout
String btntext=sharedPreferences.getString("btnkey","Yes")
btn.setText(btntext);
}
```

so when application is recreated, you find the stored `text` from `preference` and set it on the button and it's done.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem as I can see is that this line:

```
 btn.setText(sharedPreferences.getString("Name", "YES"));
```

is called before the button is initialized and found in the view. This causes the string to be set to a nullpointer which(if not try-catched) crashes the app. As long as you define the button before you set the text, no nullpointer and text is set.

```
btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
btn.setText(sharedPreferences.getString("Name", "YES"));
```